# GitHub APIを用いてリポジトリ内のファイルのコミット情報を取得したい

Tags: git, github

GitHub APIを用いてリポジトリ内のファイルのコミット情報を取得したいです。

以下のように指定すると、リポジトリ全体のコミット情報を取得してしまいます。

```
requests.get(f"https://api.github.com/repos/{OWNER}/{REPO}/commits")
```

例えば、以下のようにしてリポジトリ内の、指定したファイルの中のコミットリストを取得する方法があれば教えていただきたいです。

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{OWNER}/{REPO}/{FILE}/commits
```

Answer (score 2):

英語版にほぼ同じ内容の質問と回答がありました。

[Is it possible to get commits history for one file in github api? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15831313/2322778)

以下の形式で指定すればよいそうです。

```
http://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits?path=PATH_TO_FILE
```

例:
https://api.github.com/repos/izuzak/pmrpc/commits?path=README.markdown

詳しいドキュメントは以下になります。

http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository

Comment: 夜分遅くに失礼します。ファイルの指定まで出来ました。ありがとうございました。